# Creating array from keys and values of another array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have an array like this  $items():

```
Array
    (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [first_name] => fname1
        [laste_name] => lname1
        [Age] => 20
     )
    [1] => Array
   (
        [id] => 2
        [first_name] => fname2
        [laste_name] => lname2
        [Age] => 22
    )
  )
```

And I want to create another array only with [id] and [Age]

```
Array
    (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [Age] => 20
     )
    [1] => Array
   (
        [id] => 2
        [Age] => 22
    )
  )
```

So I have tried looping like this :

```
$array = array();
foreach($items as $item) {
     $array['id']= $item['id'];
     $array['age']= $item['age'];

 }
```

But It gives only values of the last item

Comment: just little modification needed in your code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with -

```
$array = array();
foreach($items as $item) {
   $temp['id']= $item['id'];
   $temp['age']= $item['age'];
   $array[] = $temp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with .It'll work for you.

```
$array = array();
foreach($items as $key => $item) {
     $array[$key]['id']= $item['id'];
     $array[$key]['age']= $item['age'];

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
$array = array();

$new_array = array();

foreach($items as $item) {
     $array['id']= $item['id'];
     $array['age']= $item['age'];
     $new_array[] = $array;
 }

print_r($new_array);
```

Your result is :

```
  Array
    (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [Age] => 20
     )
    [1] => Array
   (
        [id] => 2
        [Age] => 22
    )
  )
```